# Can't deploy artifacts in a remote Micro Integrator 4.2.0 instance running on Kubernetes Cluster

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-micro-integrator

I tried to deploy artifacts in a remote Micro Integrator 4.2.0 instance which running on Kubernetes Cluster ,but it didn't work, i can't find the api in the Micro Integrator server .
In the Integration Studio it shows that is deployed successfully and synchronized but when i try to invoke the api i got 404 not found ,even i checked the folder webapps i can't find any .car .

[image: deployed api]
NB : it works for binary instance in VM but for Kubernetes instance sometimes it works,sometimes no is not stable.